# Is javax.mail.Message protected from SMTP injection?

Tags: java, security, smtp

I've tried a few toy test cases, but aside from that I can't find any documentation or test cases that explicitly indicates that the class protects against basic CRLF attacks, etc.

Is there something I'm missing or should I just code defensively assuming the API offers no protection?

Answer (score 1):

JavaMail does not offer protection against CRLF attacks such as SMTP Header Injection. It is advisable to code defensively.
Check out the Workaround/Fix section in the following link. Oracle has issue.
http://osdir.com/ml/bugtraq.security/2014-05/msg00108.html